# Logic gate using transistor

Tags: digital-logic

I think it should be OR gate, my reasoning explained below:

---

[image]

---

If A is F/0V and B is F/0V then BaseEmitter of both are reverse biased and thus no current flows, (BaseCollector is at zero potential difference): F*F=F

If A is F/0V and B is T/5V  or vice versa then BaseEmitter of one is reverse biased and thus no current flows again BaseCollector is at zero potential difference for that one, but the other's BaseCollector is forward biased and current flows so C is high voltage: F*T=T

If both are T it is thus obvious current flows : T*T=T

and so gate is OR from this info?

Answer (score 4):

The question is not whether current flows, but what the voltage is.

When both A and B are false, C is connected only to +5V through the pull-up resistor.
When A or B is true, C is connected directly (without much of a voltage drop) to ground through one or both transistors.

See [open collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector) for pratical applications of this circuit.

Comment: not directly, there' a transistor in between

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is an RTL (Resistor-Transistor Logic) NOR gate.

When A and B are both low the transistors are turned off.  It's like they aren't there, so the output C is connected to +5V.  That equates to both inputs being 0 and the output being 1.

```
 A | B || C
------------
 0 | 0 || 1
```

When either transistor is turned on a path between C and ground is provided.  This means the voltage at C drops right down (almost to 0V, but not quite), so it is equal to either input being 1 and the output being 0.

```
 A | B || C
------------
 1 | 0 || 0
 0 | 1 || 0
 1 | 1 || 0
```

So you had the OR portion of it - one input **OR** the other input has an effect on the output, but what you failed to notice is the inversion provided by the pull-up resistor and the fact the transistors lower the output when on and not raise the output.

Answer (score 1):

For your edification, here are the four basic gates and their truth tables:

[image]

Comment: positive true NOR= ? NAND? NOR?

Comment: No, positive true NOR = NOR.  Putting it another way, \$ \overline{\text{C}}=A+B\$

Comment: i'm sorry it's NAND

Comment: OK, have it your way.

Comment: i mean the answer is NAND

Comment: The answer is NOR now stop arguing!

Comment: I second that - C is true when neither A **NOR** B are true.